# Why cannot exclude null type in Typescript in this scenario

Tags: typescript

```
type NonNullableCopy<O> = {
    [p in keyof O] -?: O[p] extends null | undefined ? never : O[p];
};

type Adsa = {a?: number | null}
type Basda = NonNullableCopy<Adsa>
let asd : Basda = {
    a: null // Still valid. No errors
}
```

But this work:

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;

type NonNullableCopy<O> = {
    [p in keyof O] -?: NonNullable<O[p]>;
};

type Adsa = {a?: number | null}
type Basda = NonNullableCopy<Adsa>
let asd : Basda = {
    a: null // Work. Throw errors
}
```

Why two this ones is different? Please explain to me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The type

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;
```

is a [*distributive* conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) because the type `T` being checked is a plain [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  Distributive conditional types *distribute* over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in their checked type; if `T` is a union, it's split into its members, each member is processed, and the result is joined in a new union.  So `NonNullable<A | B | C>` will be equivalent to `NonNullable<A> | NonNullable<B> | NonNullable<C>`.

Distributive types can be used for, among other things, filtering unions.  If `T` is something like `string | undefined`, then the check is `(string) extends (null | undefined)` which is false and therefore passes through, and `(undefined) extends (null | undefined)` which is true and therefore suppressed, and you get a filtered union as a result.

---

On the other hand, a type like

```
type Different<O, P extends keyof O> = O[P] extends null | undefined ? never : O[P];
```

is *not* distributive.  The type being checked, `O[P]` is a type expression more complicated than just a plain generic type parameter (it is made up of multiple type parameters and an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)).  Therefore the check happens to the entire `O[P]` input at once, even if it's a union.  So if `Different<O, P | Q | R>` will *not* generally be the same as `Different<O, P> | Different<O, Q> | Different<O, R>`.

If `O[P]` is `string | undefined`, then the check is `(string | undefined) extends (null | undefined)` which is false, and the whole thing passes through.

---

[Playground link to code](https://tsplay.dev/WG2Xom)